# How to get the data from each node in my linked list?

Tags: java, arrays, linked-list, nodes

I have a linked list containing a few nodes which each contain a string and an array, I need to move through my array so I can get to the arrays in the other nodes but I can't figure out how.

ie. nodeOne contains a string, array and a pointer to nodeTwo, this repeats until it gets to the null
I need to move to the next node so I can get at the data in the array.

-My over all goal is to get the array from each node and combine them into one array. 
Node below. Once I have the intArray I need to move to the node t and do the same, its the moving to the next node thats confusing me.

```
public Node(String identifier, Node<T> t){
        intArray = new int[8];
        head = identifier; 
        tail = t;
    }
```

Comment: Please, share your code.

Comment: Thats not what I need, I just need the data from each node i don't want to move anything.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the class code for the node you are using , since this is not the default LinkedList class in java .
But let us say you have a class called Node where your instance variable are *data1* (which is your String) & *data2* (which is your array (let us assume it is an int[] array)) and a pointer called next which is of type ***Node***
So, basically what you need is to write a method that can access all the nodes in your linked list and access the ***variable*** *data2* and concatenate it in another ***variable*** you will create in your method let us name it "*rList*"
so ,what you do is :
1st you want to access and check all nodes 
so your base case (whether you write your method iteratively or recursively)
will be 'while(currentNode.next!=null)'
then you get 'currentNode.data' and then add it to the list you will return which is *rList*